# Alter data within a nested array

Tags: php, wordpress, formidable

I have the nested array of data below which comes from the Wordpress Formidable Pro plugin form entries database table. I would like to reformat it so I can use it in a Wordpress WP_list_table but I can't work out how to alter the innermost nested array. I need each row to be formatted like `'product_id' => '4080',`

```
            Array (
                [30] => Array (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [product_id] => 4080
                )
                [31] => Array (
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [product_id] => 2942
                )
                [32] => Array (
                    [user_id] => 4
                    [product_id] => 9630
                )
                [33] => Array (
                    [user_id] => 3
                    [product_id] => 2542
                )
                [34] => Array (
                    [user_id] => 7
                    [product_id] => 1234
                )
            )
```

The code used to produce the array:

```
            global $wpdb;

            //Retrieve the bids from the database.      
            $form_entries = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM '. $wpdb->prefix .'frm_item_metas WHERE field_id in (145,147)');

            $data = array();

            foreach ( $form_entries as $meta ) {

                if ( ! isset($data[$meta->item_id])){

                    $data[$meta->item_id] = array();

                }

                $data[$meta->item_id][] = $meta->meta_value;

            }

            //rename the array keys
            foreach( $data as &$new_values ) {
              $new_values['user_id'] = $new_values[0]; unset( $new_values[0] );
              $new_values['product_id'] = $new_values[1]; unset( $new_values[1] );
            }
            unset($new_values);

        }
```

I have tried messing around with strReplace and implode() but I don't really know what I'm doing. I'd be grateful if anyone could help.

**Edit:**
Desired array:

```
            Array (
                [30] => Array (
                    'user_id' => '2',
                    'product_id' => '4080',
                )
                [31] => Array (
                    'user_id' => '5',
                    'product_id' => '2942',
                )...
```

Comment: Its not clear to me what you want,can you edit your question with the desired array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no square brackets in the array, that is just how print_r marks the keys in an array. As far as I can tell, the array is in the format you want.

Here's for better understanding of the issue... I create an array.

```
$test = array(
    30 => array( 'user_id' => '2', 'item_id' => '4080' ), 
    31 => array( 'user_id' => '5', 'item_id' => '2942' ), 
);
```

This is what `print_r($test)` makes it look like:

```
Array
(
    [30] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [item_id] => 4080
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 5
            [item_id] => 2942
        )

)
```

This is what var_export($test) makes it look like:

```
array (
  30 => 
  array (
    'user_id' => '2',
    'item_id' => '4080',
  ),
  31 => 
  array (
    'user_id' => '5',
    'item_id' => '2942',
  ),
)
```

This is what var_dump($test) makes it look like:

```
array(2) {
  [30]=>
  array(2) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["item_id"]=>
    string(4) "4080"
  }
  [31]=>
  array(2) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["item_id"]=>
    string(4) "2942"
  }
}
```

An array is a data structure that assigns values to keys; it is not the string you see when running it through a function that displays a representation of that structure.

Comment: Thanks Anke for explaining this. It means the problems I'm having must be due to something else.